# $0^0$ in a field

Tags: field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. If $0_{\mathbb{F}}\neq a\in\mathbb{F}$, then the definition of $a^k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is well known. Does the definition $(0_{\mathbb{F}})^0=1_{\mathbb{F}}$ contradicts any of the field axiom? If not, it is all right to define $0^0=1$ is $\mathbb{R}$? 
Thanks!

Comment: Exponentiation is not mentioned at all in the field axioms, so I don't know what sort of "contradiction" there could possibly be.

Comment: "*Does the definition $(0_\Bbb F)^0$...*"  what definition?

Comment: You right @JMoravitz. Sorry, I fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, although exponentiation is not defined in the field axiom but we can define it naturally by $a^3=aaa$, $a^{-2}=a^{-1}a^{-1}$ etc.

Comment: I don't see any problem, however it doesnt means much because $0^{-1}$ doesn't exists. I do think that it make sense for elements other than 0.

Comment: Thanks @yanko, but how we can get expressions like $1/0$ ? The exponentiation rules ($a^ma^n=a^{m+n}$ etc.) are valid only if the "basis" $a$ is non-zero.

Comment: "*How can we get expressions like $1/0$*?"  Why would you want to?  It is well understood that $1/0$ (*also written as $0^{-1}$*) doesn't exist (*as already mentioned*).  Afterall, what would be $0\times 0^{-1}$?  By definition of zero, it should be equal to zero, but by definition of inverse it should be equal to one, assuming $0\neq 1$ this is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i pointed out, $0^{-1}=1/0$ is not defined.

Comment: Personally, I don't remember instances in ring theory where defining $0_{\Bbb F}^0=1_{\Bbb F}$ yields disadvantages. That being said, I don't remember instances where this is advantageous either.

Comment: However, this is not a reason to define $0^0=1$ in $\Bbb R$ either: ring theory is simply oblivious of the analytical matters that prevent any choice for $0^0$ to be preferable to anoher. And said reasons are surely more important than any (*if any*) benefit that a ring-theoretic choice of notation may bring.

Comment: Anybody who refuses $0^0=1$ should be consistent and refuse, in a monoid written additively $M$, to set $0_{\mathbb{Z}}x=0_M$, for $x\in M$. The definition is exactly the same as in a multiplicative monoid.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an answers but might be related.

1. The group $\mathbb{Z}$ is acting on every group, in particular on the group generated by the invertible elements of a given field, this action is given by n.a=a^n so it does make sense to define $ a^0=1$.
2. In $\mathbb{ R }$ the expression $0^0$ is not defined, and this is because "it doesn't works well with taking limits" you can find two sequences $a_n,b_n$ convergence to 0 so that $a_n^{b_n}$ convergence to 1 or to infinity (even to -infinity).

Comment: Thanks @yanko. So if we restrict our self only to the algebraic structure of $\mathbb{R}$ (or any field), then $0^0=1$ is well define ?

Comment: "That's not an answers but might be related". So it should (arguably) be a comment.

Comment: That is too long for a comment. And yes i don't think it contradicts any algebraic axiom.